# IBM Worklight 6.1 error - User Identity Not available.

Tags: java, webview, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We have an app which opens in-app browser for a payment and we check the URL changes on the in-app browser to close the browser and call a method. The method in turns  calls an adapter procedure. But the adapter starts throwing an error. The adapter calls work unless the in-app browser is opened.

```
> [8/23/15 14:26:38:047 AST] 0000003f LoginContext  E
> com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext processRequest FWLSE0117E:
> Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message:
> An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule
> StrongBLAHBLAH, User Identity Not available. [project
> BLAHBLAHMobile61] [project BLAHBLAHMobile61] [8/23/15 14:26:38:047
> AST] 0000003f servlet       E
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An
> exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet
> [GadgetAPIServlet] in application
> [IBM_Worklight_Console_BLAHBLAHMobileTest]. Exception created :
> [com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException   at
> com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:572)
>   at
> com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:454)
>   at
> com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:431)
>   at
> com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:75)
>   at
> com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:389)
>   at
> com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:112)
>   at
> com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.getContent(BackendQueryHandler.java:182)
>   at
> com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.BackendQueryHandler.doPost(BackendQueryHandler.java:73)
>   at
> com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:141)
>   at
> com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:103)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)     at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)  at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>   at
> com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:199)
>   at
> com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
>   at
> com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:203)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:191)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
>   at
> com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>   at
> com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>   at
> com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java)
>   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java)     at
> com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
> com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
> com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this makes sense for the "failure" to happen:

As far as I know the in-app browser webview is separate than the webview that the app itself operates within and thus the data is not shared between the two.

Maybe a better solution would be to handle the payment process not via in-app browser but like what is explained in the following tutorial and you could thus move data using Java.

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-topics/integrating-server-generated-pages-hybrid-applications/

Comment: The problem is that earlier the android version of the app was working fine. But now we started seeing the same problem in android as well. We are using in-app browser at other places too but we dont see the problem there. We have a go-live today and it is very difficult to go for a new implementation. Moreover, the data movement is fine. Its just that when we close the browser and comeback to call an adapter procedure, the procedure call fails with above mentioned error.

Comment: The above tutorial supports Mobile Found 7.1. We are using Worklight 6.1

Comment: The same applies for 6.1